# CSS relative top in percent not work in Chrome

Tags: html, css

I want a sunrise-from-horizon effect.

I found that when the parent's height is auto,
the relative top in percent of the child does not work in Chrome.
But in Firefox it's ok.

The case can be simply demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/ja6Lngx4/

```
#A {
  position:relative;
  top:50%; left:50%;
}
```

---

```
<div style="width:200px;background:#aaa;">
<div id="A">123</div>
<div>ABC</div>
</div>
```

I know that if the parent's height is specified,
the top in percent will take effect,
but it's also a requirement that the parent's height must fit contents.

Can we achieve this only by CSS?
Or must we do it in Javascript?

Comment: it doesn't work in Firefox and even if it does it should not and it should be considered as a bug

Answer (score 1):

No, you can only do it in Javascript, because Chrome doe not change the layout calculation precedence even though child's top does not affect the parent's dimension. Top in percent is treated like height in percent.

In Javascript you can use `getBoundingClientRect()` to get the parent's dimension in px relative to the whole viewport, and set the child's animation using the information.